# Maven use same dependency with different versions in different modules

Tags: maven

I have dependency with version 1 and 2, also I have module A which is parent of module B.
For some reason, I need to use version 1 in module A and version 2 in module B. Is it possible?

I have tried to change version inside module B, I see that two different versions were added to class path, but version 1 is used everywhere.

Comment: Avoid that if at all possible. Otherwise look into Maven shade plugin.

Comment: If I were you, I would do anything to avoid that situation. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I made my own research about this question and understood that easier and better for the future, will be to try to replace (that will be very close to impossible for my case) one of dependency with other similar ones. For my case it was Logback and Slf4j2.